# How to Declare a two-dimensional array in RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm

I have a model/class like:

```
Class A {
var x: String
var y: String
var twoDimArray: [[ObjectB]]() // How to convert this into RealmSwift?

init()..
...
}
```

-
I have tried the following:

```
List<List<ObjectB>>()
```

but its not working

if its not available, is this available in core-data?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to have two-dimensional `List` create another `Object` class which would hold another list.

```
class A {
    let list = List<B>()
}

class B {
    let list = List<C>()
}

class C {
}
```

Comment: But I have to show the data in a UITableView with sections using this two-dimensional List/array, how that can be done with your suggest solution?

Comment: That's a different question to what you're asking above. You should separate the ideas of 'model' and 'view' - you should model your data as best as you can, and then work out how to present the model separately. Your question is regarding 2D arrays - no mention of UITableViews, and nor should there be. Find the best model from this answer, then ask a separate question if you need help on presentation after you've tried it yourself. On a separate note, your code above is a class, but not a Realm model. Use the real code, then define 'not working' as either a compile error or runtime error.

Comment: Thank you @RobertDresler for your help and explanation, this solution works!

Comment: @Naveed okay, its actually not my explanation in comment. But, you’re welcome :)

Comment: how to deal with multidimensional string var temp : [[String]]